# Running a batch script from a C++ application and check if it has an infinit loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm launching a bat file with **system()** in my software and it's can go to an infinit loop.
the question is how can I detect it in my cpp application ?
I'm using VS2010.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a thread, and let the thread do the run of your batch file, and then set a timer with a timeout in the main thread to check whether the thread has ended its execution. If it takes longer than the timeout period, stop it and claim that it has an infinite loop.

I don't see any other way, because you practically can't access the batch file.

For threads, you may use boost threads or Qt threads, and there's many more different libraries for threads.